# ReactJS Stores order

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I have a certain store--let's call it `AuthStore`--which contains an authentication script and keeps the token, which is a significant parameter for all API requests. So what I need is to fire the auth script and store the token before any other stores request the token.

My code works if the token is retrieved on `webapp` load. But if the first page the user sees is a page that requires dynamic data loaded by another store, then the token is sometimes requested from `AuthStore` by other stores before `AuthStore` actually has it.

How can I avoid this situation and ensure that the token is present before other stores request it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not perform synchronous AJAX call.

I don't know in details your implementation but let's imagine we're hitting the `page/with/dynamic/data` necessitating authentication :

```
var getStateFromStores = function() {
    return {
        authToken: AuthStore.getToken(),
        dynamicData: FooStore.getAll()
    }
}

var PageWithDynamicData = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return getStateFromStores();
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        AuthStore.addChangeEventListener(this._onChange);
        FooStore.addChangeEventListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        AuthStore.removeChangeEventListener(this._onChange);
        FooStore.removeChangeEventListener(this._onChange);
    },

    render: function() {

        if (!authToken || dynamicData.length == 0) {
            return (
                <p>Loading</p>
            )
        }

        if (dynamicData.length == 0) { //we could be authenticated but dynamic datas are not retrievied yet
            return (
                <p>Loading</p>
            )
        }

        return dynamicData.map(function (data) {
            return <Foo data={data}/>
        });

    }

    _onChange: function() {
        this.setState(getStateFromStores());
    }

});
```

The `AuthStore` should probably store the `token` in its cache and at the first call to `AuthStore.getToken()` retrieve it via an ajax call. When this ajax call resolves it will trigger an action such as `TOKEN_RECEIVED`. The `AuthStore` will responds to this action by updating its internal `token` state to store the received `token` so the next time we need it we don't need to make another ajax call. Then, the `AuthStore` emits change.

Putting it all together :

### State 1 : User first hits the page

1. User hits the `page/with/dynamic/data`
2. Your `PageWithDynamicData` gets its initial state via `getStateFromStores`
3. `AuthStore.getToken()` is called, it does not have any token at this moment so he triggers an ajax call (probably through some `WebAPIUtils` module) to retrieve it (asynchronously).
4. `FooStore.getAll()` is called. Same here, no data in cache so a call to the API is made to retrieve the data (asynchronously).
5. Since `this.state.authToken` and `this.state.dynamicData` are missing, the `PageWithDynamicData` renders at its loading state

*example:*

```
++++++++++++++++++++++
+                    +
+     "loading"      +
+                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++
```

### State 2 : dynamic data are received before token

It's totally plausible since we run asynchronous request. Let's see what happens :

1. The ajax request for dynamic data resolves and trigger a `FOO_DATA_RECEIVED` action.
2. The `FooStore` responds to this action by updating its internal state to contains the received datas.
3. `FooStore` emits change
4. `AuthStore.getToken()` is already pending so we do nothing (this could be done via `Promise` but it's outside the scope of this question)
5. `FooStore.getAll()` now returns the fetched data
6. `PageWithDynamicData` gets rendered exactly the same as before since we do not have the token.

*the same rendering occurs:*

```
++++++++++++++++++++++
+                    +
+     "loading"      +
+                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++
```

### State 3 : We receive the token

1. The request fetching from the server resolves and triggers an action `TOKEN_RECEIVED`
2. The `AuthStore` responds to this action by updating its internal state with the received token and emits change
3. The `PageWithDynamicData` receive the change and the call to `AuthStore.getToken()` and `FooStore.getAll()` now returns the correct data
4. The `PageWithDynamicData` now renders the data:

*the page now renders the data to the authenticated user :*

```
++++++++++++++++++++++
+                    +
+  - "some data"     +
+  - "another one"   +
+  - "..."           +
+                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : It's not an answer to the "how can I handle the authentication in my React application" since in this case we should probably use some session storage or whatever. But the whole point here is to demonstrate how we can "wait" for something to happen before doing anything else keeping a one-way dataflow thanks to Flux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the request for the token is "synchronous" vs. the default "asynchronous". While testing, I used jQuery for the XHR calls and ran into a similar situation. jQuery has a property that you can set for synchronous calls which will wait for the result before any further execution of code.

**UPDATE**

```
function xhr() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/url/to/data/here",
        async: false
    }).responseText;
}
```

This may need some modifying, it was off the top of my head. Here is the documentation if you plan on using jQquery: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)